# Kendo scheduler -- manually trigger appointment edit

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

In Kendo scheduler, how can I trigger the edit event of a specific appointment?

I want to directly hotlink the to a certain appointment so it looks like

> scheduler.aspx?appointment=1234

and that would include pre-loading appointment #1234 edit modal on page load.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think this can help if you want to fire the edit event manually.

`var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
var event = scheduler.dataSource.at(0); // or at(1234)
scheduler.editEvent(event);`